# Existe algum tipo de PEP8 para PHP?

Tags: php

Galera existe algum tipo de pep8 para PHP que ajuda a escrever o código mais clear ?

Comment: Olá Matheus Santos, seja muito bem vindo ao site. Já deu uma olhada no tour? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Recomendo também dar uma olhada => https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim (apesar de não é oficial do PHP), existe o [PSR](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/), no momento existem:

- [Basic Coding Standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1)
- [Coding Style Guide](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2)
- [Logger Interface](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-3)
- [Autoloading Standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4)
- [Caching Interface](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-6)
- [HTTP Message Interface](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7)
- [Container Interface](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-11)
- [Hypermedia Links](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-13)
- [Event Dispatcher](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-14)
- [HTTP Handlers](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-15)
- [Simple Cache](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-16)
- [HTTP Factories](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-17)
- [HTTP Client](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-18)

Ainda existem os que estão em "revisão" e não foram necessariamente aceitos ainda.

O estilo de código básico é o PSR-1 e PSR-2, os demais são estilos para coisas mais especificas

Uma opinião pessoal sobre tudo isso é que acho o PSR-1, PSR-2 e PSR-4 razoáveis, mas acho realmente a maior parte exagero seguir cegamente, PHP é uma linguagem de script, muitas coisas podem ser feitos de forma mais simples padronizar muitas coisas é um trabalho que as vezes beira ao exagero cego, realmente não tem porque fazer (como digo em opinião pessoal), optei por escrever no PSR-1 e PSR-2 por opção pessoal, mas o PSR-4 escolhi simplesmente por para um framework que desenvolvi e mesmo assim não o uso para todos os casos, até mesmo o uso de orientação a objetos sem necessidade soa como exagero, e as pessoas se amarram nas desculpas de que deixa algo mais organizado.

A questão não é oop é melhor procedural (ou ao contrário), o problema é o uso desnecessários de algo que as vezes pode ser simplificado, vejo muita gente escrever coisas baseadas em outras linguagens como Java achando que vão tornar algo mais fácil e quando passa o tempo notam que aquilo foi um trabalho gigante que só será usado naquele lugar, isso quando não complica mais.

Para resumir, não é porque escreveram os PSRs que você deve usar.